# What is the meaning of the highlighted sentence given below from The Washington Post?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

He lashed out on Twitter and took the unusual step of threatening a lawsuit over the result, **a move that might be called dubious in the same way that LeBron James might be called athletic.** **It is — but that’s underselling the point a bit.**

[image]

Comment: Calling LeBron athletic is like a calling a Ferrari a car.  It does not describe the full extent of his ability.  Hence, calling Trump's move dubious, in turn, does not describe the full extent of how groundless he claim is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is trivially obvious that LeBron James, a great athlete, is athletic. Thus, this comparison makes the point that it is trivially obvious that the lawsuit in question is dubious, meaning not justified. "Underselling" is equivalent to "understating", not saying something strongly enough. So, the lawsuit is worse than dubious, it's ridiculously unjustified.